# WCF server returning XML documents with ?xml-stylesheet set

Tags: wcf, serialization

I am creating a REST web service that returns XML documents by serializing .NET objects using the DataContractSerializer.  It works very nicely returning documents like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<patient xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/example">
    .....
</patient>
```

by using code like this:

```
Message MyRestMethod()
{
    Patient patientObject = new Patient() {Name="Mickey Mouse"};
    Message message = WebOperationContext.Current.CreateXmlResponse<Patient>(patientObject);
    return message;
}
```

However sometimes, the web service is used by a web browser, and so it would be much nicer if it would return documents like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/stylesheet/format.xsl" ?>
<patient xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/example">
    .....
</patient>
```

I have done some substantial digging around, and can *almost* do it by deriving my own message and overiding OnWriteBodyContents() to get access to the XmlDictionaryWriter. At this point, I then discovered that WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text) not able to write xml-stylesheet instructions.

More importantly, WCF client code receiving an xml-stylesheet processing instruction also bombs out, so even if you "hack" the stream at the character level to add it, it would need not to be sent to WCF clients...

If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having dome some substantial reading on this, the answer is that it is not sensible to add an xml-stylesheet marker in the XML being returned to the WCF client.

The   markers are processing instructions, which instruct the interpreter to process the XML document in a certain way.  In this particular case by applying an XSLT to the document.  the WCF serialisation and deserialiser both reject XML with stylesheet processing instructions, which makes sense - as in the WCF client case you do not want the processing instruction to be followed.

However, for my usecase, having the stylesheet processing instruction in when the xml is returned to a browser does make sense, so I have solved my problem by doing a conditional serialisation based on the UserAgent in the request, and in the case of it not being the WCF client application, I am adding the stylesheet to the stream thats used to create the response message.

Answer (score 0):

In such case you are most probably going to to [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960159.aspx) because xml declaration is added by message encoder and it doesn't provide any features to add any other directives.

Comment: I have avoided the custom message encoder route because my ServiceContract returns Message rather than a specific object.  This is so that the client code has full access to the message headers which is rather important in REST interfaces...

Comment: You have always access to message headers even if you use data contracts.